# browser back to previous html section

Tags: html

I have a page with many section like below.

```
<a href="anothe-page-1" name="test 1"></a>

<a href="anothe-page-2.html" name="test 2"></a>
```

When I travel from this page to anothe-page-2.html, it is possible when user click back button (from the browser) return and jump to `<a name="test 2"></a>` ?

Comment: Do you mean need links with `#`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this any of two types...

1. `<html> <head> <script>` 
   `function goBack()   {

   window.history.back()   }` 
   `</script> </head> <body>`

   `<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">`

   `</body> </html>`
2. `<a href="javascript:history.back()">back</a>`

Comment: could it possible not using any script but the browser back button?

Comment: No, as far I know you can't change how the browser button works, you need to do a new hyperlink from yourself and put the link manually inside a button or something